# Assigning a variable the output of another script possible synchronization issue

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am writing a bash script that assigns a variable the output from another bash script and echos that variable along with other information later. Code snippit:

`CONN_NUM=$(echo "$CONN" | wc -l)
CONNS=$(./netstat_conns.sh "${port[$i]}")
echo -e "${DATE};${port[$i]};${CONN_NUM};$type;$CONNS"`

What happens is that this script will echo all of the data, however CONNS gets truncated and will echo the rest of the output from the script later (at least this is what I believe is happening, I can provide more evidence if requested but it's a bit complicated).

The `./netstat_conns.sh` script runs a loop that echo's every time it runs which is the data that should be given to the CONNS variable.

./netstat_conns.sh snippit:

`do
    line=$(echo "$line" | cut -d \  -f $N  | awk -F":" '{print $1}')
    echo "$line"
done`

Is there a way to wait until the `./netstat_conns` script finishes to move on or am I wrong as to what my problem is here?

Why I think it is a synchronization issue:

I am using a NodeJs spawn process that captures the data that is echoed from my script (the first code snippit). It is supposed to capture all of the data that is echoed, however the data is truncated and shortly after it captures the rest of the data from my second code snippit.

Comment: Does any part of `netstat_conns.sh` fork a background process or write to standard error? The assignment to `CONNS` you show should block until `netstat_conns.sh` completes and capture all of its standard output.

Comment: @chepner no it does not. hmm interesting. I'll edit in the reason I think it's a synchronization issue though it probably isn't anymore